# Demoting a server in a domain with Windows 2012 and 2008 servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

We have a domain with more DC's than necessary.  Each server added to domain has become a DC.  We would like to demote a few servers.  For lack of a better word our main server is a Windows 2012 R2 Standard.  We attempted to demote a server used for storage(Windows 2012 R2 Standard) and a server running Radius(Windows 2012 R2 Standard).  The storage server type is DC and the Radius server is GC.  After these were demoted none of our users could access their storage folders and our wireless network went down.  Our users storage folders are issued on the AD user object profile page on the Home Folder section.  It is connected as a Z drive and the path is \server ip\share name. We followed the Microsoft steps to remove a domain controller.  Obviously we missed a step.  Has this happened to anyone else and what is the correct steps to demote a server, but keep it's resources available.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move GC roles from a server before demoting it from a domain controller to a member server.  I suspect that this is the step you missed.  Also, the decommissioning process moves any FSMO roles to random other servers, but if this step fails the decommission may continue, so it might be best to move them manually beforehand.

[This TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755937%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) recommends the following steps:

1. View the current operations master role holders
2. Transfer the schema master
3. Transfer the domain naming master
4. Transfer the domain-level operations master roles
5. Determine whether a domain controller is a global catalog server
6. Verify DNS registration and functionality
7. Verify communication with other domain controllers.  During the removal of Active Directory, contact with other domain controllers is required to ensure that any unreplicated changes are replicated to another domain controller, removal of the domain controller from the directory, and transfer of any remaining operations master roles.  If the domain controller cannot contact the other domain controllers during Active Directory removal, the decommissioning operation fails.
8. Verify the availability of the operations masters.  If any of the verification tests fail, do not continue until you determine and fix the problems. If these tests fail, the uninstallation is also likely to fail.
9. Optional:  If the domain controller hosts encrypted documents, export the certificate.
10. Uninstall Active Directory
11. Optional - If the domain controller hosts encrypted documents and you backed up the certificate and private key before you remove Active  Directory, re-import the certificate to the server.
12. Determine whether a Server object has child objects
13. Delete a Server object from a site

If you need a link on transferring FSMO roles, [this article](https://www.interworks.com/blogs/ijahanshahi/2014/01/20/transferring-fsmo-roles-another-active-directory-controller) looks helpful.

Comment: `You need to move any FSMO or GC roles from a server before demoting it from a domain controller to a member server` - That's not strictly true for the FSMO roles. While many people prefer to manually transfer the FSMO roles so as to "control" where they end up, they'll be transferred by the DCPROMO process to another DC automatically.

Comment: Fair enough.  They're transferred by the uninstall process, but if a failure occurs the uninstall may proceed anyway.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the domain controller role, DNS is also likely removed or at least disabled. Make sure that whatever domain controllers you have left are also configured to be DNS servers and that your clients and other servers are configured to use that DNS server.